# css grid layout column

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a layout with 5 columns using css grid. The first and the last columns should have white space.
I try to create it but somehow it turns out to be three rows instead of columns.

```css
.grid_container{
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 2fr 4fr 2fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: ". A B C ."
}

#column1 {
    grid-area: A;
    background:red;
    padding: 100px;
}

#column2 {
    grid-area: B;
    background:blue;
}

#column3{
    grid-area: C;
    background: orange;
}
```

I have the 5 columns but the first and the fifth columns should have whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the most important property `display: grid`. The example in CodePen [Grid columns](https://codepen.io/sigfriedCub/pen/NmaaqJ). Cheers, sigfried.